# Proper usage of subjunctive in sentence

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctives

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> I would highly recommend the GEMS school to restrict the usage of public transportation for field trips.

or

> I would highly recommend GEMS school to restrict the usage of public transportation for field trips.

Comment: Why do you think the use of the subjunctive is related to the presence of **the**? Please explain your concerns.

Comment: Where is the subjunctive in your sentences? I can't see any!

Comment: An example of sentence using the Subjunctive Mood would be *I highly recommend that the GEMS school restrict the usage of public transportation for field trips.* As @JeffreyCarney said, the presence of the article doesn't make the sentence not grammatical, nor does that make any difference as a matter of using the Subjunctive Mood.

Comment: @apaderno Yes, but English doesn't have a subjunctive mood, like Latin does. It's more accurate to call it a subjunctive **construction**, consisting of a clause headed by a plain form verb.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, but English learners will still speak of _Subjunctive Mood_ because the books they read use that term. I just wanted to write an example sentence.